# Not able to see more than 65536 records even after converting the file

Tags: excel

I have saved more than 450k records in excel 97-2003 version. I realized that I could see only 65,536 records. I searched in google and understood that I had to convert the file to excel workbook and I tried that. Still I could see only 65,536 records. I tried to copy the records and paste in new excel workbook but I could see only 65,536. How do I see all the records?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 can only store [up to 65536 records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/work-around-the-excel-2003-row-limitation?view=sql-server-ver15). Thus, converting it to a workbook (whatever that means) won't help.